# Forcing user to enter certain pattern when request input

Tags: c++

Is there some way of forcing the user to enter a certain pattern when I request input?

For example, If I request they enter five numbers (xx x xx)

I was wondering maybe an array that I can enter my pattern into, then it be matched to the input, but not for value obviously.

I do not know how I would do this (if its possible).
I am a beginner, as you can tell, so I thought I would come here cause you would know. If this is not possible, how else can this be done?

Comment: With standard C++ input you can't force the user to do anything.  You can just refuse to accept what they give you.  So if you tell them what to enter and they don't do it you could just tell them they have to reenter the information until they get it right.  There are ways of doing what you want but it requires extra libraries like curses.

Answer (score 0):

You can write while loop where you'll enter your input while some condition is true.

```
while(std::cin >> input){
  if (checkInput(input))
    break;
}
```

Function checkInput will check your input and returns true if your input matches some requirements.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean simply with the correct location of spaces?  If so perhaps you could read the third character in the string and the 5th and if they are anything other than whitespace then reject it.  Maybe something like

```
while (true) {
  std::cout << "input: ";
  std::string input;
  std::cin >> input; // e.g. "12 3 45"

  char const correct1 = input[2];

  if (correct1 == ' ') {
    break;  
  } else {
    std::cout << "Incorrect pattern";  
  }
}
```

You would then do the same for the 5th character
This may be entirely incorrect but thats roughly what I would do.

Answer (score 0):

You should have a while loop checking the input and breaking when the input is the correct pattern you want.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
int main() {
 char numbers;
 cout << "Enter 5 numbers: ";
 cin >> numbers;

 while(!checkForValidPattern(numbers)) {
  cout << "Try 5 numbers XXXXX : ";
  cin >> numbers;
 }

 cout << "numbers = " << numbers << endl; 
 return 0;
}
```

Of course, you will have to create the validation function and it depends on your specific need.

Comment: The link is dead.

Answer (score 0):

For matching patterns in string I use the regex functions from the standard library (https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex)
You can use this site to test regular expressions : https://regex101.com/

```
#include <cassert>
#include <regex>

bool is_valid_input(const std::string& input)
{
    // (xx x xx) needs pattern "\(\d{2} \d \d{2}\)" 
    // in code you get even more backslashes

    static std::regex rx{ "\\(\\d{2} \\d \\d{2}\\)" };
    static std::smatch match;
    return std::regex_match(input, match, rx);
};

int main()
{
    const std::string good_input{ "(12 3 45)" };
    const std::string bad_input{ "(x3 4 55" };

    assert(is_valid_input(good_input));
    assert(!is_valid_input(bad_input));
}
```